# Flutter Animation Coming After each other

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I want two animated texts to happen after each other, but they happen simultaneously. What is something that would allow them to work after each other.

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignupScreen> createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  // Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {

  bool work = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 80,
        ),
        AnimatedTextKit(
          animatedTexts: [
            TyperAnimatedText(
              'It all started with an',
              textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Itim", fontSize: 40),
            )
          ],
          isRepeatingAnimation: false,
           // I WANT THE SAME ANIMATED TEXT TO HAPPEN AFTER THIS
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from the package documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit#typer

```dart
return SizedBox(
  width: 250.0,
  child: DefaultTextStyle(
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 30.0,
      fontFamily: 'Bobbers',
    ),
    child: AnimatedTextKit(
      animatedTexts: [
        TyperAnimatedText('It is not enough to do your best,'),
        TyperAnimatedText('you must know what to do,'),
        TyperAnimatedText('and then do your best'),
        TyperAnimatedText('- W.Edwards Deming'),
      ],
      onTap: () {
        print("Tap Event");
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Please use it like this:

```dart
Column(
              children: [
                AnimatedTextKit(
                  animatedTexts: [
                    TyperAnimatedText('It is not enough to do your best,'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('you must know what to do,'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('and then do your best'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('- W.Edwards Deming'),
                  ],
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Tap Event");
                  },
                ),
                AnimatedTextKit(
                  animatedTexts: [
                    TyperAnimatedText('It is not enough to do your best,'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('you must know what to do,'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('and then do your best'),
                    TyperAnimatedText('- W.Edwards Deming'),
                  ],
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Tap Event");
                  },
                ),
              ],
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear when I asked my question. I want both of them to appear at the same time, and if I used this way the first one will when the second one is there.